# Win7 UAC Keep Poping up after adding manifest

Tags: winforms, registry, manifest, uac

VS2008 C# winforms with deployment project.
I need to access registry to store settings.
but to do that I need to add an external manifest to the project.
Without the manifest included the application cannot access registry.

(is there another way?)

manifest as just one setting:
   requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"

I made sure that assemblyIdentity version match the project name and version.

with manifest included all works well, BUT User access control keep popping up EVERY time I launch the application. 
Why does the UAC nor remember user clicked OK last time?
I am happy with user clicking it once but not every time.
What is required to charge this?
thanks

Comment: This is normal of course.  Use keys in HKCU instead of HKLM to avoid having to ask for elevation.

Comment: yes thanks that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than marking your application as `requireAdministrator`, mark it as `asInvoker`.

Then for those limited places where you absolutely do require administrator access, relaunch a copy of your app using ShellExecute and the magical **runas** verb.

It will trigger UAC consent dialog and run your app as an administrator.